# Batch File which checks for another Batch File process

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, tasklist

so google didn't help me at all i need to ask here again.
I use this kind of method to check if my servers are running in 2 batch files.

```
tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq server_64.exe" 2> nul | find "server_64.exe" > nul
IF ERRORLEVEL == 1 (
echo Server is not running
echo.
) else (
echo Stopping Server ...
echo.
taskkill /F /IM server_64.exe > nul 2>&1
)
```

One to start and one to stop the servers.
Well this works great but when it comes to batch files it wont work for me...
I have one server which runs on phyton so start it via batch file.
My question is, is there a way to get somehow the batch file process status and stop it like it works for exe?
I hope i explained it good enough.
Thx in advance! :)

Comment: `IF %ERRORLEVEL% == 1 (` or `IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (` although these `IF` does not give the same results, see http://ss64.com/nt/if.html and http://ss64.com/nt/find.html

Comment: @JosefZ, preferrably `IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 1` (the `==` operator forces string comparison, `EQU` does numerical comparison when both expressions are purely numeric; and `IF ERRORLEVEL 1` actually means `IF ERRORLEVEL >= 1`, but some commands might use negative `ERRORLEVEL` values also)...

Comment: the script works for exe files like it should just not for batch files.

Answer (score 0):

You can try it with a batch file like this :

```
@echo off 
set "Process=server_64.exe"
Title Checking for status of this process ===^> "%Process%"
tasklist /nh /fi "imagename eq %Process%" 2>nul |find /i "%Process%" >nul
IF '%ERRORLEVEL%' EQU '1' (
    Color 0B
    echo.
    echo "%Process%" is not running
) else (
    Color 0C
    echo.
    echo Stopping "%Process%" ...
    taskkill /F /IM "%Process%" > nul 2>&1
)
pause
```

Comment: you got me wrong, maybe i didnt explained it good enough. i need to check the tasklist for a batch file which is running not a exe file which works good. i have a batch file which starts a phyton script and i want to check for the cmd which actually runs the script. when i try to use "xyz.bat" where i use "server_64.exe" it wont work.

Comment: i even tried to compile the batch to an exe file to find it in the tasklist but it wont work for some reason.

Comment: tasklist /FI "WINDOWTITLE eq Administrator: Broker"2>NUL | find /I /N "cmd.exe"2>NUL  wont work im getting frustrated because google wont help me at all xD and it doesnt make a difference if i use "Administrator: " as prefix or not both just gave me error level 1 duh...

Answer (score 0):

Omg i found the solution, this was a beast...

```
tasklist /fi "imagename eq cmd.exe" /v /fo table /nh | find /i "Broker" 2>nul
```

but what is starmnge is that i cant get the output to be silnce...
when i try to mute it it gives me always error level 1.

```
tasklist /fi "imagename eq cmd.exe" /v /fo table /nh 2>nul | find /i "Broker" 2>nul
```

so whats wrong with this? ^

Comment: duh im realy sorry! its just >nul instead 0f 2>nul